# Describe Impala Query Metadata

Tags: metadata, impala, describe

Is there a way of getting the metadata of a query?

I can use [DESCRIBE](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_describe.html) but this only applies to tables, I don't really want to have to create a table from the query and get the metadata of that table as that would be unnecessarily expensive even if I limited the result rows.

I'm using impala shell to output queries to delimited files (usually only a couple of hundred rows) which are sometimes needed to be imported into an Access database.

I'd like to know the data types as then I can make Access use the correct data types rather than defaulting to string.

Comment: You could `CREATE VIEW xxxx AS`, then `DESCRIBE xxxx`, then `DROP VIEW xxxx`. No need to execute it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, do you want to stick it as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: Nah... that trick is not really worth 15 pts *(it works with any database that supports views, by the way)*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter marking as an answer will help many people looking for answers (or looking to answer) to know that it is an accepted answer.  It's a good answer -- go for it :-)

Comment: ...or @Tim could update the title so that it shows `[Solved] Describe Impala Query Metadata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, thanks to @SamsonScharfrichter is

> CREATE VIEW xxxx AS, then DESCRIBE xxxx, then DROP VIEW xxxx.